# Node express routes as modules: where to put `require`s?

Tags: node.js, express, module, url-routing

Node Express's [Routing guide](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) gives the following example for creating routes as modules:

***/birds.js***:

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

// middleware that is specific to this router
router.use(function timeLog (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time: ', Date.now())
  next()
})
// define the home page route
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Birds home page')
})
// define the about route
router.get('/about', function (req, res) {
  res.send('About birds')
})

module.exports = router
```

***/app.js***:

```
var birds = require('./birds')

// ...

app.use('/birds', birds)
```

I want to know why they put the first two lines of `birds.js` there instead of in `app.js`.

Firstly, `app.js` calls a method of `app`. How is `app` supposed to be defined within `app.js`? I take it they (oddly) neglected to include that necessary code for the sake of the tutorial.

Secondly, say I wanted a second route as a module, for dogs as well as birds, in a file called `dogs.js`. Could it look identical to `birds.js` WRT the first two lines? AFAIK that would result in two instances of express. (Or three if it's needed in `app.js` as well?!)

Comment: I agree this is very unclear. In `/birds.js`, it should have been `var app = express();` somewhere...
Also, I suppose that as long as you define **once** your express app, it doesn't matter where you define it (app or module).

Comment: @Valberthe thanks - so it would be *ok* to define the express app *more* than once?

Comment: No. You should always invoke one express instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example is not complete. The whole app setup is left out (i asume because it is explained further up in the docs anyway and replaced with `// ...`). In your app.js you need at least:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

The first 2 lines in bird.js have nothing to do with the two (missing) lines in app.js. You need them to create a router.

And regarding your last question: Yes, you would create another router exactly like the bird router. A router is not an express app/instance and it's totally fine to have multiple of them in you app.

Comment: Great, thanks - so would you recommend to simply add the two lines you provided to `app.js`? Or would that still not be entirely complete or good practice, given the rest of the code?

Comment: well, yes. But you might want to add other stuff all routes need like bodyparser, ...